# I'm trying to add previous and next arrows to this content slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently there are circles at the bottom that can be used to navigate between slides. I would like to add next and previous arrows to the sides that the user can click on to proceed forwards or back through the slides.

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    transition: left 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#contentContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#navLinks {
    margin-top:-61px;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
}
    #navLinks ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 6px;
    }
        #navLinks ul li {
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 10px;
            list-style: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.8);
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
            #navLinks ul li:hover {
                background-color: #FFF;
            }
            #navLinks ul li.active {
                background-color: rgba(156,227,100,0.9);
                color: #FFFFFF;

            }
                #navLinks ul li.active:hover {
                    background-color: red;
                    color:#FFF;

                }

#itemOne {
    background-image: url("http://telcospace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/android_eating_apple_1000x500_by_crus23-d38bpx9-640x300.jpg");
}
#itemTwo {
    background-image: url("http://www.thetimesofhealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Angry-Baby-Face-500x300.jpg");
}
#itemThree {
    background-image: url("http://animalsugar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/baby-cat-hd-wallpapers-baby-cat-widescreen.jpg");
}
#itemFour {
    background-image: url("http://cuteimages.net/data/2015/5/the-first-puppy-to-leave-me-speechless-name-cuteimages.net.png");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="itemOne" class="content">

        </div>
        <div id="itemTwo" class="content">

        </div>
        <div id="itemThree" class="content">

        </div>
        <div id="itemFour" class="content">

        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
 <div id="navLinks">
    <ul>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="0px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-500px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-1000px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-1500px"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemLinks");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

var activeLink = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);

    link.itemID = i;
}

links[activeLink].classList.add("active");

function setClickedItem(e) {
    removeActiveLinks();
    resetTimer();

    var clickedLink = e.target;
    activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;

    changePosition(clickedLink);
}

function removeActiveLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}

function changePosition(link) {
    link.classList.add("active");

    var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");
    wrapper.style.left = position;
}

var timeoutID;

function startTimer() {
    timeoutID = window.setInterval(goToNextItem, 2963);
}
startTimer();

function resetTimer() {
    window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
    startTimer();
}

function goToNextItem() {
    removeActiveLinks();

    if (activeLink < links.length - 1) {
        activeLink++;
    } else {
        activeLink = 0;
    }

    var newLink = links[activeLink];
    changePosition(newLink);
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stormbloom/2d0a1215/

I would like to learn this for personal experience, otherwise I would just use a plugin like WowSlider. If it's easier to do this by building a new slider from scratch then any links to resources explaining how to accomplish this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting a custom slider with arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach with arrows, just tweak with the design.

In the HTML I added the correspoding arrows, and in the JS I added the `EventListeners` and the function `goToPreviousItem()` at the end.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemLinks");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

document.querySelector('#previous').addEventListener('click', goToPreviousItem, false);
document.querySelector('#next').addEventListener('click', goToNextItem, false);
 
var activeLink = 0;
 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);
 
    link.itemID = i;
}
 
links[activeLink].classList.add("active");
 
function setClickedItem(e) {
    removeActiveLinks();
 resetTimer();
 
    var clickedLink = e.target;
    activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;
 
    changePosition(clickedLink);
}
 
function removeActiveLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}
 
function changePosition(link) {
    link.classList.add("active");
 
    var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");
    wrapper.style.left = position;
}

var timeoutID;
 
function startTimer() {
    timeoutID = window.setInterval(goToNextItem, 2963);
}
//startTimer();
 
function resetTimer() {
    window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
    startTimer();
}
 
function goToNextItem() {
    removeActiveLinks();
 
    if (activeLink < links.length - 1) {
        activeLink++;
    } else {
        activeLink = 0;
    }
 
    var newLink = links[activeLink];
    changePosition(newLink);
}

function goToPreviousItem() {
   removeActiveLinks();
    
    if(activeLink == 0) {
        activeLink = links.length - 1;
    } else {
        activeLink--;
    }
    
    var newLink = links[activeLink];
    changePosition(newLink);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
 transition: left 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#outsideContainer {
    width: 600px;
}
#previous {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
#next {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
#contentContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navLinks {
 margin-top:-61px;
 position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
}
    #navLinks ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 6px;
    }
        #navLinks ul li {
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 10px;
            list-style: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.8);
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border:rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 1px solid;
   box-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff;
        }
            #navLinks ul li:hover {
                background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    border:rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 1px solid;
            }
            #navLinks ul li.active {
                background-color: rgba(156,227,100,0.9);
                color: #FFFFFF;
                outline-width: 1px;
    
            }
                #navLinks ul li.active:hover {
                    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
                    color: #FFFFFF;
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
     border:rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 1px solid;
                }

#itemOne {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url("http://telcospace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/android_eating_apple_1000x500_by_crus23-d38bpx9-640x300.jpg");
}
#itemTwo {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url("http://www.thetimesofhealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Angry-Baby-Face-500x300.jpg");
}
#itemThree {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url("http://animalsugar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/baby-cat-hd-wallpapers-baby-cat-widescreen.jpg");
}
#itemFour {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url("http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/28100000/Katy-Perry-gifs-katy-perry-28147211-500-300.gif");
}
```

```html
<div id="outsideContainer">
    <div id="previous"><<</div>
    <div id="contentContainer">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="itemOne" class="content"></div>
            <div id="itemTwo" class="content"></div>
            <div id="itemThree" class="content"></div>
            <div id="itemFour" class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="next">>></div>
</div>

 <div id="navLinks">
    <ul>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="0px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-500px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-1000px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-1500px"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan for the sweet and simple answer!